# Употребление предлога "за"

Tags: предлоги

Будет ли ошибкой употребление предлога "***за***" в предложении: "Он готов умереть **за** неё"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Употребление корректное.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> ― Я начинал с вами эту опасную игру, ― продолжал Половинкин, ― и я был **готов умереть за нее**. [Алексей Иванов. Земля -- Сортировочная (1990-1991)]
>
> Но что всего удивительнее, это то, что в цитированном выше письме к матери Н. Н. Гончаровой от 5 апреля 1830 года Пушкин пишет: «Бог мне свидетель, что я **готов умереть за нее**; но умереть для того, чтобы оставить ее блестящей вдовой, вольной на другой день выбрать себе нового мужа, ― эта мысль для меня ― ад». [А. А. Ахматова. «Каменный гость» Пушкина (1947)]

Comment: Так обычно говорят, когда имеют в виду "ради неё". А если имеется в виду "вместо неё", так тоже корректно говорить?

Comment: @grizzly  Думаю, нужно говорить "умереть вместо неё", так как в данном контексте "за нее" имеет другой смысл. Сравните: поработать за нее (вместо нее).